# how do I extract a date stamp from a file name stored in a bash variable

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a bash variable $filename that looks like this

```
[rmerritt@server]$ echo $filename
/opt/project/xxxx/async_transaction__2023-05-28.csv
```

what I am hoping to do is extract that date stamp 2023-05-28 and store it in another bash variable $dateis that allows me to do this

```
 cp /opt/project/xxxx/*`echo $dateis`*.csv|/opt/project/jdev/data/landing/landing_xxxx/
```

I.E. copy all csv files with that datestamp to another directory any idea how I could do this in a oneliner ? I have tried using awk

```
cp `ls  -Art   /opt/project/xxxx/*__*.csv` /opt/project/jdev/data/landing/landing_xxxx/
```

Comment: I'm surprised that none of the answers you've gotten are using bash's built-in regex support; `[[ $string =~ $regex ]]` is a lot faster and more efficient than `echo "$string" | grep -o "$regex"`.

Comment: You only provide an example, but don't specify the general rule, i.e. does the string always end in `...YYYY_MM_DD.csv`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU bash and its builtin [parameter expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
filename="/opt/project/xxxx/async_transaction__2023-05-28.csv"
date="${filename##*_}"
date="${date%.*}"
echo "$date"
```

Output:

```
2023-05-28
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are certain this is always the exact format, you can do:

```
$ dateis=${filename: -14:-4}

$ echo $dateis
2023-05-28
```

Comment: that wont work for me as the first part of the filename might change

Comment: @R.Merrit: That's why the characters are counted from the end. It does not matter what's in the first part.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `grep -o` to extract the date easily:

```
$ filename=/opt/project/xxxx/async_transaction__2023-05-28.csv
$ dateis=$(echo "${filename}" | grep -o "202[0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]")
$ echo $dateis
2023-05-28
```

Change the regular expression as you wish to keep it simple and work for all your cases.

**EDIT:** If you have a lot of files, it's wise to follow @user1934428 suggestion and avoid calling additional programs/piping. One minimal change to fix that would be to use "Here String" instead:

```
$ filename=/opt/project/xxxx/async_transaction__2023-05-28.csv
$ dateis=$(grep -o "202[0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]" <<< "${filename}")
$ echo $dateis
2023-05-28
```

Comment: dateis=$(echo "${filename}" | grep -o "202[0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]")| cp /opt/project/xxxx/*${dateis}*.csv /opt/project/jdev/data/landing/landing_xxxx/ -v   seems to have done it ...thanks Jardel

Comment: This works, but I'm downvoting because you unnecessarily create two child processes connected in a  pipe. Imagine that someone wants to adapt this solution for a large array of filenames - you certainly don't want to create separate child processes for each array element.

Comment: @user1934428 thanks for the feedback. I edited the answer with an alternative.

Comment: Your alternative still uses an unnecessary child process (for running `grep`). If you go for a regex solution, why don't you use the regex matching which is built into bash itself?

Comment: Thanks again @user1934428. I think we will keep the downvote now since I believe following your last comment would disrupt the balance of fixing the problem vs keeping it easy to understand given the context of the OP. Migrating the regex from `grep` to builtin `bash` would lead to a somehow obscure syntax for newcomers. I don't see the benefit in performance justifies that specially since it's not an explicit demand; it's unlikely the OP is running the script in such large number of files.

Comment: You'll may state writing more pure bash is even simpler regardless, though requiring more syntax knowledge; I wouldn't disagree. This is more a personal viewpoint of what constitutes a good answer I think.

Comment: As I said before, creating an unnecessary child process could matter in a loop, i.e. when we process many files. That's why I try to avoid it in answer, **if** I find an alternative which does not need to spawn. As for the syntax, I personally don't find the bash syntax unusual or obscure; it is after all very similar to matching i.e. glob pattern, and even a newcomer should be familiar with the `[[ ... ]]` syntax. It's IMHO not more or less obscure than process substitution, or understanding which options to feed into _grep_. But this is of course a matter of taste.